# JQuery: Calculating

Tags: jquery, django

i have this jquery script example, does anyone know why it's not working ?. I using this script on django.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doCalc() {
    var total = 0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('span.amount').html($('input:eq(0)', this).val() * $('input:eq(1)', this).val());
    });
    $('.amount').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
    });
    $('div.total_amount').html(total);
}
$('button').click(doCalc);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    doCalc();

});
</script>
</head>
```

There are no error on console browser.

```
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th width="20%">Value</th>
        <th width="20%">Quantity</th>
        <th class="actions">Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_1" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_1_1" value="0"></td>
        <td>$<span class="amount"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_2" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="var_2_2" value="0"></td>
        <td>$<span class="amount"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><strong>Total event cost (viability)</strong></td>
        <td><strong>$<div class="total_amount">total</div></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table><button>Go!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

if i want to add another text field to calculate what should i do ?. Thank you.

Comment: One problem is that the initial 'tr' selector will also select the Total event cost row. A useful trick is to add an class='item' to each row you want to go into the sum, then change the selector to $('.item')

Comment: I don't think there is any point in looking for find(('span.amount'). Just find('.amount')

Comment: Next your previous rows are calculating an amount, so there is no need to do it twice. The tr selector can also calculate the total

Comment: Your code works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/r3z33/

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's working now. I forgot to add this script $(document).ready( function() { $('button').click(doCalc); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class for quantity. The value of input fields with this classname are used as multiplier; values of regular fields are added:

```
<tr>
  <td> .. amount</td>
  <td><input class="quantity" .. ></td>
</tr>
```

Try something like this:

```
var $rows = $('table tbody tr');
var total = 0;

$rows.each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var rowTotal = 0;
  $('input', $this).each(function () {
    rowTotal = $(this).hasClass('quantity') ? rowTotal * parseInt($(this).val(), 10) : rowTotal + parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $('amount', $this).text(rowTotal);
  total += rowTotal;
});

$('. total_amount').text(total);
```

In this way you can add as many input fields within your table rows as you want.

Comment: Doesn't work because it doesn't multiple the item cost by the unit cost on each row. :-(

Comment: Updated the code example so you can use 1 or more inputs on each row as quantity.